# Social network DB model in MongoDB

Tags: database-design, mongodb

I am building a story site for pre school

The basic functions are students will be posting stories and others will be able to like/comment on that story

Below is the model of the DB

```
Stories
Story_Id
StoryTitle
StoryContent
StoryAuthor
StoryLikes {
LikerId,LikedTime
}
StoryComments{
AuthorId,AuthorComment
}
```

Is this model OK? How else can this be remodelled?

The problem I see here is, if I store it in this way, will be it faster when I query for all comments by a particular user and so on?

Comment: The problem is that there is a size limit for BSON documents, and you are likely going to hit it with that model. Please see http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/

Answer (score 1):

According to above mentioned description it seems that **story comments** is a separate collection which will encapsulate comments related to several stories along with **story Id**.But that approach will cause a performance overhead since it will require multiple queries for retrieval of information.As an alternate solution comments can be stored into **stories** collection as embedded documents which will consume less time duration of retrieval of comments
Embedded documents are alternative to joins in MongoDB
For more detailed description regarding embedded documents please refer the documentation as mentioned in following URL

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: That's a horrible idea, because of the BSON size limit of 16MB. Furthermore, the performance issue depends on the point in time you need the information. E.g.: For a ***given*** story, what are the comments? So if a story "page" is selected, you'd have only two queries, which can be optimized to be rather fast ***and*** be scalable till the end of days.